# UiTableView on iPhone showing only first row on iOS 10.0

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ios10

I am experimenting a weird behavior with the tableView on iPhone only.
The problem is that the UITableView which updates automatically while loading data would show on iPhone only the first row and as I scroll down the other rows start appearing, This behavior started with iOS 10.0 and only on iPhone. On iPad it works correctly.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:  (NSInteger)section {
// Return the number of rows in the section.
     return [searchResultsArray count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"searchResultCell" owner:self options:nil];
        }
        else {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"searchResultCell~iphone" owner:self options:nil];
        }


        cell = referenceCell;
        self.referenceCell = nil;
        self.referenceCell.tag = indexPath.row;
    }
    NSMutableDictionary *referenceDict = [searchResultsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    label.text = [referenceDict objectForKey:@"TEXT"];

    UIView *cellView = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:5];
    BOOL colorBack = [[referenceDict objectForKey:@"COLOR"]intValue];
    if (colorBack) {
        cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"light gray.png"]];
    }
    else {
        cellView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed: @"sepia.png"]];
    }
    cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test threads in which the code is running inside cellForRowAtIndexPath. I've had similar problems in this method in iOS10 while work with view layer